# Govt Office Env, No Server installed, MS SQL server Management Studio. Can I restore database & practice

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I work in restricted govt office, I am provided with Microsoft SQL server Mgmt Studio but server is not installed and I cannot download or get access.
Question: I have downloaded "Adventureworks2019" and couple other databases. Is there a way to practice without installed server ? Is there a online server, that I can point? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try SQL Server LocalDB you might be able to get that running using your existing permissions

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to practice without installed server ?

Unfortunately, no. A server instance of SQL Server needs to be running, in order to be able to access databases and execute T-SQL. You would either need to have them install an instance locally on your machine or spin up a dedicated server for one.

> Is there a online server, that I can point?

Yes - sort of. You can practice SQL with some of the online tools such as [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/) which offers multiple database systems and versions to choose from, inclusive of SQL Server. You won't be able to attach your own database to it (such as `AdventureWorks`) though.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

"SqlServer Management Studio" is to databases what "Google Chrome" is to web pages - a tool that allows you to access and work with those [remote] entities, but cannot "host" those entities for itself.

Question: What are you trying to *achieve*?

If you're a DBA and you're trying to get grips with Database Management, Recovery and so on, then not having a database server is *completely untenable*.
If so, go back to your Management and tell them that you can't do your job without one.

If you're trying "trying something out", then you'll *still* need to go back to your Management, this time to explain what you're trying to do and why you need a database server to perform your investigations with.
You will, likely, be met with stiff resistance.
Government agencies should be very, very "hot" on Data Protection regulations and databases are a prime candidate for storing Personal Data that, perhaps, shouldn't be there and isn't covered by corporate/governmental Privacy Policies (exceeded only by those pecky spreadsheets on peoples' computers).

Answer (score 0):

Try raising a ticket to get you access to AdventureWorks on a development server. This will avoid problems with security audits etc.